# How to create unit tests for a Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, ios-keyboard-extension

Is it possible to create unit tests for files inside a KeyboardExtension target?

Comment: What have you tried so far that makes you think is not possible?

Comment: I tried to create a testing target using the extension as host app... it does not appear as a possible choice